# How to compare the complexity of different RNN cells?

Tags: rnn

I want to compare three different types of RNNs to decide which architecture can handle my data best.

To do that, I want them to have the same complexity. Can I simply define the complexity by the number of trainable parameters? If not, why?

Suppose I can compute the network's complexity like this, how do I correctly compute the complexity of a vanilla RNN cell, a GRU cell and an LSTM cell?

Comment: Just for clarity, you would like to compare space and time complexity across rnn layer classes in terms of scalability?

Answer (score 1):

One proxy for complexity is training time. You can benchmark different architectures to see how running time differs.